# save gtk.DrawingArea to file

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to save gtk.DrawingArea() object contents to jpeg file using PIL. Particularly I want add to [this script](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/webcam-viewer.html)  possibility to make photo. I found how to [save image to jpeg](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.014.htp). All I need - get pixbuf object from gtk.DrawingArea() object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not married to the idea of using gstreamer, you can use OpenCV instead. [This post](http://www.jperla.com/blog/2007/09/26/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux/) gives a great example using pygame.

However, you can get the pixbuf this way (and you don't even need PIL):

```
def get_picture(self, event, data):
    drawable = self.movie_window.window
    colormap = drawable.get_colormap()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, 8, *drawable.get_size())
    pixbuf = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(drawable, colormap, 0,0,0,0, *drawable.get_size())
    pixbuf.save(r'somefile.png', 'png')
    pixbuf.save(r'somefile.jpeg', 'jpeg')
```

and then just create a button and bind the command to `get_picture`.

Of course, if I were writing this program I would actually grab the image to an `Image` in the first place and then draw it on the `gtk.DrawingArea` - that would allow you to do all sorts of [fun things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLx4LiMtM4Y).

Comment: I am sorry. It's 2020 now and I still push it. But if I can ask, where the pixbuf.save() (pixbuf.savev()) saves the image by default?

Comment: @fsevenm I'm not sure - I'd check the gtk/gdk pixbuf docs