# Save the contents of a Gtk.DrawingArea or Cairo pattern to an image on disk

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, pygobject, pycairo

I've got a small PyGI project which uses a [Cairo image surface](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/reference/surfaces.html#class-imagesurface-surface), which I then scale with a [surface pattern](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/reference/patterns.html#class-surfacepattern-pattern) and render on a Gtk.DrawingArea.

I'd like to write the **scaled** version to a PNG file. I've tried to write from the original surface with [Surface.write_to_png()](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.Surface.write_to_png), but it only writes in the original (i.e. non-scaled) size, so I'm stuck in there.

Then I thought I could perhaps fetch the rendered image from the Gtk.DrawingArea and write that to disk, but I haven't found out how to do that in PyGI (this seems to be only possible in GTK+ 2 - [save gtk.DrawingArea to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254499/save-gtk-drawingarea-to-file)). So I'm trying to figure out how I can write my scaled image to disk.

Here's the code that creates the surface, scales it up and renders it:

```py
def on_drawingarea1_draw (self, widget, ctx, data=None):

    # 'widget' is a Gtk.DrawingArea
    # 'ctx' is the Cairo context

    text = self.ui.entry1.get_text()
    if text == '':
        return

    # Get the data and encode it into the image
    version, size, im = qrencode.encode(text)
    im = im.convert('RGBA') # Cairo expects RGB

    # Create a pixel array from the PIL image
    bytearr = array.array('B', im.tostring())
    height, width = im.size

    # Convert the PIL image to a Cairo surface
    self.surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(bytearr,
                                                 cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32,
                                                 width, height,
                                                 width * 4)

    # Scale the image
    imgpat = cairo.SurfacePattern(self.surface)

    scaler = cairo.Matrix()
    scaler.scale(1.0/self.scale_factor, 1.0/self.scale_factor)
    imgpat.set_matrix(scaler)
    ctx.set_source(imgpat)

    # Render the image
    ctx.paint()
```

And here's the code to write the surface to a PNG file:

```py
def on_toolbuttonSave_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    if not self.surface:
        return

    # The following two lines did not seem to work
    # ctx = cairo.Context(self.surface)
    # ctx.scale(self.scale_factor, self.scale_factor)

    self.surface.write_to_png('/tmp/test.png')
```

So writing the surface creates an non-scaled image, and there is no write method in the cairo.SurfacePattern either.

My last resort is to fetch the scaled image as rendered in the gtk.DrawingArea, put it in a GtkPixbuf.Pixbuf or in a new surface, and then write that to disk. The pixbuf approach seemed to work in GTK+ 2, but not in GTK+ 3.

So does anyone know how I can write the scaled image to disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a way:

Remembering that *Gtk.DrawingArea* derives from *Gtk.Window*, I could use the `Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window()` function to get the contents of the drawing area into a *GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf* and then use the `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.savev()` function to write the pixbuf as an image on disk.

```py
def drawing_area_write(self):
    # drawingarea1 is a Gtk.DrawingArea
    window = self.ui.drawingarea1.get_window()

    # Some code to get the coordinates for the image, which is centered in the
    # in the drawing area. You can ignore it for the purpose of this example
    src_x, src_y = self.get_centered_coordinates(self.ui.drawingarea1,
                                                 self.surface)
    image_height = self.surface.get_height() * self.scale_factor
    image_width = self.surface.get_width() * self.scale_factor

    # Fetch what we rendered on the drawing area into a pixbuf
    pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(window, src_x, src_y,
                                      image_width, image_height)

    # Write the pixbuf as a PNG image to disk
    pixbuf.savev('/tmp/testimage.png', 'png', [], [])
```

While this works, it'd still be nice to see if someone could confirm this is the right way or to see if there is any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach, using the Cairo context passed to the handler of draw events, but it resulted in capturing a region of the parent window that was larger than the DrawingArea.

What worked for me was to use the PixBuf as you have shown, but first calling the queue_draw() method for the DrawingArea, to force a full rendering, and waiting for the event to be processed (easy enough, I already had a draw handler). Otherwise, the resulting images can be partially undrawn.