# How to convert plot in gtk canvas from pyplot to pixbuf in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I'm plotting something using matplotlib in python and want to show the plot in GTK. I'm following [this](http://www.freesbi.ch/en/python/plot-gtk) tutorial. The problem is I want to embedded the plot in textview. So I want to convert it to pixbuf and append it to textview.

It's not a problem if I save it first and load it later as a pixbuf and append it to textview. But, I want to do it directly without saving any file.

Below is a sample code from [link](http://www.freesbi.ch/en/python/plot-gtk)

```
self.figure = Figure(figsize=(100, 100), dpi=75)
self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(111) 
self.canvas = FigureCanvasGTK(self.figure) # a gtk.DrawingArea
self.canvas.show()
self.graphview = builder.get_object("plot")
self.graphview.pack_start(self.canvas, True, True)
```

Can I convert the plot in `self.canvas` into `pixbuf` so that I can embedded it to `textview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a class, which uses GdkPixbuf as the backend of metaploitlib, full source code and demo can be found here: [metaploitlib_backend_pixbuf](https://github.com/LiuLang/gtk-test/tree/master/metaploitlib_backend_pixbuf)

If we get a pixbuf, then we can easily insert it to a textview.

Below is the screenshot which uses GtkImage to display that pixbuf:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it works, but how to get a white background? and although it works, but I get this message: `AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'`

Comment: from link [above](http://www.freesbi.ch/en/python/plot-gtk), he said that canvas will return a gtkdrawingarea and i think i can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892411/save-the-contents-of-a-gtk-drawingarea-or-cairo-pattern-to-an-image-on-disk), but it didn't work :(

Comment: okay, to solved error in my first comment, add this: `matplotlib.use('Agg')`. now, how to get pixbuf with white background?

Comment: Cannot you modify canvas data (like background color) with mataploitlib??

Comment: ah, sorry. the solution is plt.figure(facecolor='w'). I thought I should do it with cairo :p

Comment: Please add some information about how this is actually achieved. Right now, this answer is little more than a link.