# Save the contents of a gtk_drawing_area or Cairo pattern to an image on disk

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

How do you save the contents of a gtk_drawing_area or cairo context to disk?

similar to this (Python) question: [Save the contents of a Gtk.DrawingArea or Cairo pattern to an image on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892411/save-the-contents-of-a-gtk-drawingarea-or-cairo-pattern-to-an-image-on-disk)

but in C.

Answer (score 1):

The Python code you linked doesn't seem to do anything different from what a C program would do; you would just need to look up the equivalent C methods, like [`gdk_pixbuf_savev()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-savev).

However, because your original question said cairo pattern*, I supposed you deduced that since you write the implementation of the GtkDrawingArea `draw` signal handler, you could reuse that code to draw to an image. You're correct.

In that case, you would first create [an image surface](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html) and then [a `cairo_t` from that surface](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-create). Pass that to your drawing function, and then [you can save the surface to a PNG](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-surface-write-to-png). [Here's an example (from the Pango documentation).](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Cairo-Rendering.html#pango-Cairo-Rendering.description)

Of course, this assumes your `draw` handler is written such that it doesn't use either the GtkDrawingArea or the `data` parameter. If it does, you'll need to split the actual drawing logic out. Either way, hope that helps!

*I'm assuming you meant cairo context or cairo surface. A pattern is just a definition for how a drawing operation draws; saving that to an image is somewhat meaningless. (You can create patterns out of images, yes, but that still doesn't mean much for saving.)