# How to get pixels from Gtk.DrawingArea?

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm writing a simple paint like application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk


class Application(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, title='paint')
        self.connect('destroy', self.__on_destroy)
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        drawing_area.conenct('draw', self.__on_draw)
        vbox.pack_start(drawing_area, True, True, 2)
        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def __on_draw(self, widget, g):
        g.set_source_rgb(200, 0, 0)
        g.move_to(16, 0)
        g.line_to(16, 32)
        g.stroke()

    def save_to_file(self, filename):
        # How to get pixels from drawing_area?
        pass

    def __on_destroy(self, e):
        Gtk.main_quit()

app = Application()
Gtk.main()
```

Now I want to save user drawing. How can I access pixels inside Gtk.DrawingArea widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from this following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892411/save-the-contents-of-a-gtk-drawingarea-or-cairo-pattern-to-an-image-on-disk)

> `Gtk.DrawingArea` derives from `Gtk.Window`.Hence you can use
>   `Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window()` to get the contents of the drawing area
>   into a `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf` and then use the `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.savev()`
>   function to write the pixbuf as an image on disk.

You can follow the link for complete code.Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254499/save-gtk-drawingarea-to-file) can also help you.